# Bitcoin consensus and server of miners

Tags: consensus

I know consensus is what 51% thinking.My questions is where miners communicated?On what server,what port??Where??The must push own api (copy of blocks) for thinking of consensus.So where BTC miners pushing api,for where blockchain explorer used it,where?

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin Network is a P2P network made up of independently operating nodes from all over the world. Miners will connect to this network in order to maintain a view of the network's state, which is crucial to their participation as a miner.

By connecting to the network, a node (and/or miner) will receive and relay information from its peers, about new transactions and blocks. Nodes communicate using TCP, and the standard port is 8333. For a deeper dive into the specifics of the gossip protocol, [see this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/67335/how-is-bitcoin-transactions-and-the-blockchain-as-a-whole-transferred-over-the-i/67348#67348).

Comment: Thanx.That's help me,because i dont understand P2P network,for comunicate they must have some server,some http or https address where they can use info(broadcast),and where they can push info to other nodes/miners.

Answer (score 1):

> The must push own api (copy of blocks) for thinking of consensus

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for an API specifically for managing consensus.

I believe consensus is a kind of emergent property that arises naturally from the ordinary communication between Bitcoin nodes, the sharing of blocks of data.

It is intentional that consensus arise but so far as I know, there is not a specific separate consensus protocol whose job is only to create consensus.

Consensus means that virtually all Bitcoin nodes have the same data, the same view of which blocks are valid. This arises because they all apply the same rules concerning block validity and they all actively share information about blocks they know of.

There is no API for consensus specifically. The API needed for obtaining new blocks in order to find out receipt of payments etc is also sufficient for a node to compare its own copy of the blockchain with another's (or to compare several other nodes' copies with each other). The node can then apply standard rules about which blocks to save and which to discard.

It probably does require some careful thought to design a data sharing protocol in which the accumulation of data at nodes acts in a convergent rather than divergent fashion. It evidently does not need a separate "consensus" API.